# Filtering a Query based on a Date and Window function in Snowflake

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, sql-view, snowflake-schema

I was asked to pull information about three different types of clients in the last year (visited once, visited <10 times, and visited over 10 times) see if the likelihood of them returning compared to a few different factors.

For this reason, I created a pretty broad query. Currently I have a joined query of three tables: client information, visit information, and staff information. I created a calculated column in my select statement:

`COUNT(DISTINCT visitno) OVER(PARTITION BY clientid) as totalvisits`

Now I just need to group by totalvisits and filter by date they visited.

I tried:

```
where visitdate> 01/01/2021
group by totalvisits
having total visits<10
```

But I get an error that the visitno is not a valid group by expression.

What might I be doing wrong?

Comment: Please include sample data-set and expected output in question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, so lets make some fake data, and do the count thing:

```
WITH fake_data(client_id, visit_date) as (
    SELECT * FROM VALUES
    -- this person has visted once
    (1, '2022-04-14'::date),
    -- this person has visited 3 timw in the year
    (3, '2022-04-13'::date),
    (3, '2022-03-13'::date),
    (3, '2022-02-13'::date),
    -- this person is a huge vistor, but 1 is outside the with in last year.
    (5, '2022-04-12'::date),
    (5, '2022-03-12'::date),
    (5, '2022-02-12'::date),
    (5, '2022-01-12'::date),
    (5, '2020-02-12'::date)
)
SELECT *,
    count(distinct visit_date) over (partition by client_id) as total_visits
FROM fake_data
WHERE visit_date >= dateadd('year', -1, '2022-04-14' /* CURRENT_DATE */)
```

boom:

| CLIENT_ID | VISIT_DATE | TOTAL_VISITS |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2022-04-14 | 1 |
| 3 | 2022-04-13 | 3 |
| 3 | 2022-03-13 | 3 |
| 3 | 2022-02-13 | 3 |
| 5 | 2022-04-12 | 4 |
| 5 | 2022-03-12 | 4 |
| 5 | 2022-02-12 | 4 |

Now to make those into those thee group/categories.

```
SELECT *,
    count(distinct visit_date) over (partition by client_id) as total_visits,
    case 
        when total_visits = 1 then 1
        when total_visits <= 3 then 2
        when total_visits > 3 then 3
    end as group_id
FROM fake_data
WHERE visit_date >= dateadd('year', -1, '2022-04-14' /* CURRENT_DATE */)
```

Now some math, of which I will wrap that into a sub-select (but also push a couple things down into it)

```
WITH fake_data(client_id, visit_date) as (
    SELECT * FROM VALUES
    -- this person has visted once
    (1, '2022-04-14'::date),
    -- this person has visited 3 timw in the year
    (3, '2022-04-13'::date),
    (3, '2022-04-11'::date),
    (3, '2022-04-09'::date),
    -- this person is a huge vistor, but 1 is outside the with in last year.
    (5, '2022-04-12'::date),
    (5, '2022-03-12'::date),
    (5, '2022-02-12'::date),
    (5, '2022-01-12'::date),
    (5, '2020-02-12'::date)
)
SELECT group_id
    ,count(distinct client_id) as count_of_group_members
    ,sum(total_visits) as sum_of_group_visit
    ,avg(visit_gap_in_days) as avg_group_day_diff
    ,stddev(visit_gap_in_days) as stddev_group_day_diff
FROM (
SELECT *,
    count(distinct visit_date) over (partition by client_id) as total_visits,
    case 
        when total_visits = 1 then 1
        when total_visits <= 3 then 2
        when total_visits > 3 then 3
    end as group_id,
    lag(visit_date) over (partition by client_id order by visit_date) as prior_visit_date,
    datediff('day', prior_visit_date, visit_date) as visit_gap_in_days
FROM fake_data
WHERE visit_date >= dateadd('year', -1, '2022-04-14' /* CURRENT_DATE */)
)
GROUP BY 1
ORDER BY 1
```

| GROUP_ID | COUNT_OF_GROUP_MEMBERS | SUM_OF_GROUP_VISIT | AVG_GROUP_DAY_DIFF | STDDEV_GROUP_DAY_DIFF |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 1 |  |  |
| 2 | 1 | 9 | 2 | 0 |
| 3 | 1 | 16 | 30 | 1.732050808 |

Wozers, that sum of visits is wrong, I have summed my sums..

So here given the `count(distinct visitno)` I cannot sum that, as it becomes the sum of sums, AND I cannot do a count(*) because we have just noticed there are duplicates (otherwise the distinct is not needed). And I assume you have not stripped the rows down, as there is some "other details that you will want"

But anyways. This is the great things about SQL, you can answer anything, but you have to know the Question, and know the Data so you can know which assumptions can be held true for your data.

Comment: This is super helpful, thank you! I just need the aggregate column to help with filtering/dividing the population so it can get pulled into some BI reports. I will however, need to report the distribution of visits within those groups of people.

Answer (score 2):

In snowflake, you can use the [QUALIFY](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/constructs/qualify.html) clause to filter window functions post window aggregation.

So, the query would look like this:

```sql
SELECT
  clientid,
  COUNT(DISTINCT visitno) OVER(PARTITION BY clientid) as totalvisits
FROM <your_table>
WHERE visitdate >= 2021-01-01::date
  AND visitdate < 2022-01-01::date
QUALIFY totalvisits < 10;
```

*Make sure that `visitdate` has a date type beforehand, though!

**[Referring to the comment below]**: If you wanted to see the total amount of visits historically, plus the total amount of visits on a given year, you can do the following:

```sql
SELECT
  clientid,
  YEAR(visitdate) as visit_date_year,
  COUNT(DISTINCT visitno) OVER (PARTITION BY clientid) as totalvisits,
  COUNT(DISTINCT visitno) OVER (PARTITION BY clientid, YEAR(visitdate) as total_visits_by_year
FROM <your_table>
QUALIFY total_visits_by_year < 10;
```

Comment: Actually this leaves me with just the number of visits within that period of time in the totalvisit count column. Is there a way to keep that number as a total count of all time but only show the rows of visits in that period of time?

Comment: Yes, you can create two different columns: one partitioning by clientid, that will give you the total amount of visits historically; and another one, where you partition by clientid and year, where you will get the total amount of visits on a given year. I will add that to the answer.